# Calculating average of user inputted-numbers

Tags: c, user-input

With this code in C:

```
int main() {

    double score1;
    double score2;
    double averageScore;

    printf("Please enter your score in course1.");
    scanf("%lf", &course1_score);

    printf("Please enter your score in course2.");
    scanf("%lf", &course1_score);

    averageScore = (score1 + score2)/2;

    printf("Your average score is %d%%", &averageScore );
    return 0;

}
```

No matter what numbers I enter, the output keeps giving me: "Your average score is 1606416176%".

Why does this happen?

Comment: Your last `printf` call is wrong.

Comment: you scanf one variable course1_score, but use another variable score1, typo?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is here:

```
printf("Your average score is %d%%", &averageScore );
```

You're using the `%d` format specifier which expects an `int`.  The value you're printing is a `double`, so you need the `%f` format specifier.  Also, you should be passing in `averageScore`, not `&averageScore`.

The value you were getting was the address of the `averageScore` variable, interpreted as an `int`.  Since this address tends to be the same on each run (but not necessarily), you keep seeing the same value.

So this line should instead be:

```
printf("Your average score is %f%%", averageScore );
```

Also, there seems to be a typo:

```
printf("Please enter your score in course1.");
scanf("%lf", &course1_score);

printf("Please enter your score in course2.");
scanf("%lf", &course1_score);
```

Perhaps you meant `score1` and `score2`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main(  )
{
  double score1 = 0;
  double score2 = 0;
  double averageScore = 0;
  double total = 0;
  printf( "Please enter your score in course 1.\n" );
  scanf( " %lf", &score1 );

  printf( "Please enter your score in course 2.\n" );
  scanf( " %lf", &score2 );

  total = score1 + score2;
  printf( " Total score = %5.2lf \n", total );
  averageScore = ( score1 + score2 ) / 2;

  printf( "Your average score is %5.2lf", averageScore );

  getchar(  );
  return ( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Actually, `%lf` requires C99 or newer. `%f` is sufficient.

Comment: This is a problem, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Olaf `%lf` requires C99 for `printf` only. To read a `double` you have to use `%lf`.

Comment: Why the variables now declared at file scope, why adding the `5.2` not part of the question, why all these extra wasted whitespaces, why the `getchar` call, why the parens after `return`? Why?

Comment: @ouah: The initial answer did not include `scanf` (strange enough this is not in the history anymore).